# Responsive non equal size image gallery

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hi been working on this https://codepen.io/junedc/pen/yqXVaR to be responsive but to no avail.  If I remove the height or change to percentage the image was lost.

```
<div class="gallery-height">
<div class="img" style="height:125px; "></div>
<div class="img" style="height:400px;background-image: url('http://13.210.222.166/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/office1.jpg');"></div>
<div class="img" style="height:130px;"></div>
<div class="img" style="height:300px;background-image: url('http://13.210.222.166/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/office2.jpg');"></div>
<div class="img" style="height:300px;background-image: url('http://13.210.222.166/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/office3.jpg');"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how should it work on a smaller screen

Comment: Do you have to use it as a background image? If not, use bootstrap with img-fluid. For the grid, change the direction of the flex from flex-direction: row; to flex-direction: column; using media queries

Comment: i need to display 3 images as displayed/layout in the codepen,  whether it's inside a div or inside a image tag should be fine as long as it gives the said layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use it as a background image in the css, here's a trick I like to use in my projects:

```
url('http...') no-repeat center center fixed;

-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```